# How to numerically integrate $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ikt}}{1+t^2} dt$?

Tags: numerical-methods, complex-integration, numerical-calculus

How should one numerically integrate a complex exponential function like

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ikt}}{1+t^2} dt$$

Using Euler's formula

$$\sum_{t=-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (kt) + i \sin (kt)}{1+t^2} \Delta t$$

does not seem to give the same result as the analytic answer, which is convergent and entirely real:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ikt}}{1+t^2} dt = \pi e^{-|k|}$$

Comment: I think you meant to approximate the integral as $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\frac{\cos k\tau+i\sin k\tau}{1+k^2\tau^2}\tau$ for some small $\tau>0$.

Comment: @J.G. i am confused as to how the imaginary $i$ portion will vanish completely upon integration

Comment: The terms with negative $k$ will cancel the terms with positive $k$.

Comment: @James Depending on your numerical integration technique you might get a nonzero imaginary part. However, the size of this imaginary part is bounded by the error term in the integration, and will go to zero as you make the numerical integration more accurate.

Comment: @JohnBarber thank you. i will just test it out.

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes it does equal $\pi e^{-|k|}$. And it knew nothing at all of contour integration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ikt}}{1+t^2} dt$$

First you can use the symmetry to simplify it,

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ikt}}{1+t^2} dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kt)}{1+t^2} dt-i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kt)}{1+t^2} dt$$

The second integral vanishes, since the sine function is odd on $\mathbb{R}$. We can fold the first integral since the cosine function is even on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, we get

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ikt}}{1+t^2} dt=2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kt)}{1+t^2} dt$$

Now you have converted the complex integral into a real integral, so it is better for you can apply the numerical method to integrate it.